# Silverstripe, find unused media file

Tags: file, silverstripe

i've a site that have many media file, like 5000, many of these files are unused. How can i make a query on SilverStripe DB to find unused record and delete if from the DB and from FS?

Comment: First loop through the DataObjects and Pages and check the has_one, has_many and many_many relationships and check for the classes File and Image. You can use something like $dataObjects = SS_ClassLoader::instance()->getManifest()->getDescendantsOf('DataObject'); and $pages = SS_ClassLoader::instance()->getManifest()->getDescendantsOf('SiteTree'); to get the classes.  Then use $classObject = Injector::inst()->get($className); and use $classObject->has_one(), $classObject->has_many() and $classObject->many_many()  to get the relationships. Store used File, Image in an array, delete the rest.

Comment: You will also need to check the HTMLText fields to see if an image has been placed inline.

Comment: @GavinBruce that sounds more like an answer than a comment to me.